# RegEx to replace pattern in text file containing carriage returns (using Notepad2 and C#)

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a text file containing the following string:

```
--jonesj (release 00)
some sql goes here

--jonesj (release 01)
some sql goes here

--smithb (release 01)
some sql goes here
```

What I want to do is replace all commented-out SQL with an empty string.  The resulting string would look like this:

```
some sql goes here

some sql goes here

some sql goes here
```

Using Notepad2 as my testing grounds before implementing this in my code, I am trying the RegEx of `^--.*$`.  However, this appears to be highlighting the entire text file.  I am terrible at RegEx and hope someone can help me along here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work by explicitly matching the end of line chars \r\n in Multiline mode. This has the benefit of replacing the newlines too (i.e no empty line where the comment was)

```
var input=@"--jonesj (release 00)
some sql goes here

--jonesj (release 01)
some sql goes here

--smithb (release 01)
some sql goes here";

var cleaned=Regex.Replace(
    input,
    @"^--.*(\r)?\n",
    string.Empty,
    RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: For some reason can't edit, but regex should be `^--.*(\r)?\n` (i.e. 0 or 1 matches against \r, not 1 or more)

Comment: Apparently, that RegexOptions.Multiline burns me every time.

Comment: Will work fine for MS line endings, but not unix-style line endings. My correction addresses this. I have a suspicion that some SCMs can change line endings, so it's prudent to make the change.

Comment: BTW, if you're finding regex difficult, I'd recommend the free "Rad Software Regular Expression Designer" for crafting your skills. Notepad++ regex is pretty poor. http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away with this:

```
var pieces = Regex.Split(input, "--[^\(]*\(release \d\d\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^--[^\n\r]*$` to make sure the wild card won't match newlines and in greedy mode just match the whole file.